# How do I use a custom generator for IDisposable types?

Tags: c#, fscheck

**Please note: This is a question regarding `fscheck` and not on the general use of `IDisposable` in C#**

Let's say I have the following class (exaggeration for illustration purposes):

```
public class MyDataTypeWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private MyDataType fMyDataType; // MyDataType implements IDisposable

    public MyDataTypeWrapper(int[] randomData)
    {
         // some conversion routine (not shown)
         var inputToMyDataType = ConvertRandomDataToMyDataInputs(randomData);

         // this could all be done in one method but breaking out into two to illustrate.
         fMyDataType = new MyDataType(inputToMyDataType);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
         fMyDataType.Dispose();
    }
}
```

`MyDataType` consumes some unmanaged resources, hence it implements `IDisposable`. The `MyDataType` class doesn't actually have a constructor taking `int[]`, hence the use of the wrapper class.

It's relatively simple to create a generator for this, but I can't see any way for such a generator to also take responsibility for disposing of the created object after each test iteration, meaning my test code is often littered with explicit calls to `Dispose`. See an outline example below.

```
var generator = from randomData in Arb.Generate<int[]>()
                select new MyDataTypeWrapper(randomData);

// use the generator as input to some fscheck property based tests
Prop.ForAll(generator.ToArbitrary(), (MyDataTypeWrapper randomClassUnderTest) =>
{
    // want to avoid this
    using(randomClassUnderTest)
    {
        // assert some properties
        ...
    }
}).QuickCheckThrowOnFailure();

Prop.ForAll(generator.ToArbitrary(), (MyDataTypeWrapper randomClassUnderTest) =>
{
    // assert some properties
    ...

    // also want to avoid this (equivilant to use of using in example above)
    randomClassUnderTest.Dispose();
}).QuickCheckThrowOnFailure();
```

Any thoughts \ suggestions on how to avoid this would be appreciated.

Comment: `using` block ?

Comment: ok - where would it go? And it's not really different from the explicit call to Dispose (i.e. it lives inside the test delegate).

Comment: It is the consumer of an IDisposable that is responsible for disposing it so I don't really understand your question. If you create an instance of an IDisposable you should always expose it as soon as you are done using it, either explicitly by calling Dispose() or by wrapping it in a using statement. The fact that you may be using a generator or factory to create the instance doesn't change this.

Comment: Write a `Prop.ForAllDisposable` that explicitly disposes every element passed through it. This is obviously unsafe in general, so extending/shadowing `Prop.ForAll` to do that for all disposables is possible, but ill-advised. You can also write an `IEnumerable` wrapper that disposes the previous element of the enumeration it's wrapping on every call to `Enumerator.MoveNext`, which is more general (and again, not something to do arbitrarily).

Comment: You could create a wrapper for the property instead of the generator e.g. `public static Func<T, bool> Using<T>(Func<T, bool> f) where T : IDisposable { return x => { using(x) return f(x); };}`

Comment: @mm8 I don't agree with that - you could share the same instance of any IDisposable across multiple consumers, so you certainly wouldn't want the first consumer that finishes with the object to dispose it.

Comment: @Lee - interesting though it still boils down to using a `using` statement or calling `Dispose` directly. I'd ideally like a solution in the `fscheck` framework for this, if possible.

Comment: @cristobalito: The one who creates it would generally dispose it. That's the class that is creating/using the generator in this case I suppose. Sharing the same instance across multiple consumers can be done using an interface, i.e. each consumer get an IMyDataTypeWrapper that doesn't know anything about the actual implementation being disposable.

Comment: No consumer can know it is the *last* consumer, however. The only one who knows when it's safe to dispose everything in that case is you. If you really intend to share the generated objects across consumers, the only safe way is to `.ToList()` all the objects when generated, and `foreach` over them with a `.Dispose()` call at the end. The generator you use above will create new instances every time it's evaluated, so it's not unreasonable to dispose its elements immediately.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm not proposing to share across consumers - was just an example of why I disagreed with the comment.

Comment: @mm8 - agreed. My point is that it's the `fscheck` generator in this case generating the object, not the test code. By test code, I mean the code between the `{...}` in the `Prop.ForAll(...)` method.

Comment: What test framework do you use?

Comment: @artek - this is a question about `fscheck`

Comment: @kurt-schelfthout wondering if you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: @EricLippert It was intended to be a constructor - apologies for the confusion, wrote the code outside and IDE. I've fixed up the example.

Comment: _"The `MyDataType` class doesn't actually have a constructor taking int[], hence the use of the wrapper class."_ ... and yet you're calling exactly that in your example code.

Comment: @Nyerguds - fair point. The example is wrong - I'll fix it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is rather obvious but I will state it anyway because it actually answers the question:

```
var generator = from randomData in Arb.Generate<int[]>()
                select new MyDataTypeWrapper(randomData);

Prop.ForAll(generator.ToArbitrary(), (MyDataTypeWrapper randomClassUnderTest) =>
{

   using(randomClassUnderTest)
   {

   }

}).QuickCheckThrowOnFailure();
```

If you don't want to do it for every element you'd need to create some helper methods that will do that for you, e.g:

```
  public static WhateverItReturns DisposablePropAll<TDisposable>(this IEnumerable<TDisposable> elements, Action<TDisposable> action) where TDisposable : IDisposable
        {
            return Prop.ForAll(elements, (TDisposable randomClassUnderTest) =>
            {
                using (randomClassUnderTest)
                {
                    action(randomClassUnderTest);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time but what you've suggested is functionally equivalent to my sample code. This question is really about whether or not there is some native support for generators which create IDisposable objects in `fscheck`.